# Binding Text Blocks in a Master to Shape Data on the Master

Tags: visio

I'm returning to Visio after being a power user in the 2000's. A lot of what I'd do back in the day was create custom masters and associate data with the shape with individual labels etc. on those masters. Sort of a multi-part shape bound to the shape data on a given master, with fine-tuned arrangement.

The shapesheet seems entirely gone in 2016 Pro and now we have the data graphic features, which are nice and interesting, but they don't give you the same degree of fine-tuning and baked-in support that my old approach of building custom masters did.

How would I go about taking a text block on a master and binding it inside that master to the master's shape data for a given property? I'm betting it's a custom expression, but I'm not sure what the syntax would be.

Oh, my overall use case here: I want to have a shape with fine-tuned fields that are always visible, but appear in different compartments on the shape. I want to link external data into the shape and have the text blocks pull the value out of the shape data and render it for the area in question. I may use Data Graphics for ancillary things on a case by case basis, but at a core, I know I want certain features to always be present in a master and styled in certain ways.

Comment: Hi, Matt ! I think more suitable place for this question is [Super User Forum](https://superuser.com)

Comment: Thanks! I'll repost it there later if I haven't gotten a good resolution on this one. The answer below looks promising, but I'll have to verify. I didn't know the forum existed and I agree - that's likely a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

to display the property of another shape you need to reference it in the form:
sheet!N.prop.X
N being the ID of the other shape, in your case the parent.
Store this value in a intermediate field, the use insert/field.
Here's a tool to do this automatically: http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=6318.0

To handle input options to custom properties I recommend the following
1) set up a custom property of the page as semi-colon separated list for holding the desired values. eg: prop.myOption = "A;B;C"
2) in the shape needing this option, set up am according field as fixed list. In the format cell write: thePage!prop.options.

That's it. This way you can edit the list in one central place and have all the shapes updated.